# Terminal Icon to show multiple action alternatives

Tags: command-line, icons, 17.04

I like to ssh into various different systems.  I have set up a gnome-terminal.desktop file, like so (edited to show full contents of file):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=Use the command line
Keywords=shell;prompt;command;commandline;cmd;
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnome-terminal/index.html
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-terminal
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.6.1
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Keywords=Run;
Actions=heywood;dimboola;echuca;spencer;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal

[Desktop Action heywood]
Name=Heywood
Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Heywood

[Desktop Action dimboola]
Name=Dimboola
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Dimboola -x ssh dimboola

[Desktop Action echuca]
Name=Echuca
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Echuca -x ssh echuca

[Desktop Action spencer]
Name=Spencer
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Spencer -x ssh spencer
```

My question is: How do I make the alternatives (heywood, dimboola, echuca, spencer) appear in the icon pull-down (right-click)?  I have seen it done, but I cannot find any information on how to do it.

The list does appear when you go to the menu line and select File -> Open Terminal, but not in the icon pull down.

Comment: Please add the full content of your `gnome-terminal.desktop` -file.

Comment: You may need to unlock the current launcher icon, run your desktop file, then lock that to the launcher.

Comment: Still wasn't the complete one, it missed essential first line(s) It couldn't possibly work *at all* . I added them, assuming they are in the file (since you mentioned it was a working `.desktop`file). What remains unclear to me: what do you mean by: *"when you go to the menu line and select File -> Open Terminal*"? It is quite impossible items from the launcher appear in the application's menu.

Comment: That's a very good comment!   I had not noticed that those lines were missing.  They were there a long time ago (when I observed the pull down list working) in about Ubuntu 14.04.  They must have got lost in an upgrade (story of my life :-), and now I have re-instated them, all works well.  I may not have expressed the problem very well before, but the items did appear in the File_>Open Terminal pull down, and hence led further to my confusion.  Thanks for your help, much appreciated!